# fixing the position of hover box in plotly for r

Tags: r, plotly

I have a plotly generated widget which I need to embed into a webpage. The small space where I must embed it leads to the text being offset from the hover box (see pic)

[image]

Increasing the space for the plot on the web page is not an option and decreasing the font size of the hover info is also not an option, it'll get unreadable.

**Question**: How can I anchor the hover box to always display at the bottom of the plot, such that the hover info remains inside the box?

I did search the internet a bit, but wasn't successful. Is it even possible to set the position of the box?

**Edit:**
Here is a sample code which shows how the plot widget gets created. Note however, that you have to resize your browser window and make it smaller, so that the hover box behaves in this wierd fashion.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

dt.plot.data    <- data.table(value=90)

ggp <- ggplot(dt.plot.data, aes(1, y=value, fill="dummy", text="Info 1: foo<br>Info2: bar<br>date:<br>2018-05-30")) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity") + ggtitle("Performance") + labs(y="%") + theme_bw() +
        scale_fill_manual(values=c("#EE68FD")) +
        theme(  
                plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5), legend.position="none",
                axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.line.y=element_line(color="black"),
                axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
                #panel.grid.major.y=element_line(linetype="dashed"), panel.grid.minor.y=element_line(linetype="dashed"),
                panel.border=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank()
        )
#ggp

ply.yaxis       <- list(autorange=FALSE, range=c(0, 100))
ply.title       <- list(font=list(size=11), bordercolor="black", bgcolor="grey")
ply.hoverlabel  <- list(bordercolor="white", font=list(color="white", size=11))

ply <- ggplotly(ggp, dynamicTicks=TRUE, tooltip=c("y", "text")) %>% 
        layout(hoverlabel=ply.hoverlabel, yaxis=ply.yaxis) %>%
        config(displayModeBar=FALSE)
ply$sizingPolicy$padding <- 0
ply
```

Comment: Can you show a code sample instead of a picture? This would allow us to try for ourselves.

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question. Just keep in mind, that the widget initially displays correct. Only when I resize the window to be smaller, then this behaviour appears.

Comment: try [textposition](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#bar-textposition). In python you can set this to outside. Or try to set an anchor. For annotations in R you can anchor right or left.